# Microsoft teams GraphAPI returning errors

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I am having an issue with hitting POST APIs(send message, create channel) from our `Graph API`  app.

First request is for create channel:
Request URL: h`ttps://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/id/channels`

Post Body:
`{:displayName=>"new channel", :description=>"description"}`

Headers also include the bearer token from the authorization API
Error received:
`{:code=>"BadRequest", :message=>"channel cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: channel", :innerError=>{:date=>"2020-06-24T12:40:33", :"request-id"=>"be91ce7b-0"}}`

Documentation that I followed: `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http`

Second request is of send message to channel:

Request URL: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/bc71-8b158cc3b3/channels/19:ec73841@thread.skype/messages`

Post Body:

`{:body => {:contentType=>"html", :content=>"Tesing message from graph api"}}`

Headers also include the bearer token from the authorization API

Error received:
`{:code=>"InternalServerError", :message=>"Failed to execute request.", :innerError=>{:date=>"2020-06-24T12:42:01", :"request-id"=>"ed601c89-f0bd3"}}`

Documentation that I followed: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: how do you send your request? from javascript? or from postman? are your get-requests working, meaning can you get the team in your first request you are creating a channel for?

Comment: Just cross verified and bot v1.0 and beta are working fine. Where are you trying this? 
Check your token once in jwt.io, verify you have all the required permissions.

Comment: Your both requests are working fine at my end. Please re verify or give more information about request details